# how to set icons in angular according to screen size?

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design

The graphic designer gave me for each icon he created different sizes.
How to make integrate them in angular html file ?

How to use the biggest icons for desktop, smaller for tablets and smallest for mobile ?

Answer (score 0):

hide each icons when you don't want to show them

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>       
        <div id="big-icon" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-md"></div>
        <div id="small-icon" class="hidden-lg hidden-xs hidden-md"></div>
        <div id="smallest-icon" class="hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md"></div>
</body>
```